# Match mesh on top of another

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

I am making a costume for a character. I have the costume ready, but parts of the modelling mesh keeps on slipping through it. How do I make the costume completely cover the model mesh? This is my exact problem:[image]

Comment: you could hide the underneath mesh with a Mask modifier

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to use the *Shrinkwrap* modifier. Just add it to the costume object and set the model mesh as the target object. Enable *Keep Above Surface* and adjust the offset value, so your costume mesh will stay above the model mesh.

[image]

With the *Shrinkwrap* modifier your costume mesh will follow the exact shape of the target mesh, so the mesh will be modified. But if you just want to completely cover the model without changing the costume mesh, use the *Displace* modifier - tweak the *Strength* value.

[image]